# Android: extend Linearlayout, but need same for RelativeLayout. Duplicate code unavoidable?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this code:

```
public class CopyOfLinearLayoutEntry extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private CheckedTextView _checkbox;
    private Context c;

    public CopyOfLinearLayoutEntry(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.c = context;
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public CopyOfLinearLayoutEntry(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.c = context;
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
        strokePaint.setARGB(200, 255, 230, 230);
        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        Rect r = canvas.getClipBounds();
        Rect outline = new Rect(1, 1, r.right - 1, r.bottom - 1);
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, r.top, r.right, r.top, strokePaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // find checked text view
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof CheckedTextView) {
                _checkbox = (CheckedTextView) v;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return _checkbox != null ? _checkbox.isChecked() : false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (_checkbox != null) {
            _checkbox.setChecked(checked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if (_checkbox != null) {
            _checkbox.toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I also need a version for RelativeLayout, so I would duplicate the class file and replace "extends LinearLayout" with "extends RelativeLayout". I think that would be bad, because I do not want any duplicate code.

How would I go about achieving my goal, seeing that Java does not allow multiple inheritance?

I read something about the composition design pattern, but I am not sure how to implement that.

Maybe someone could give me a starting point as to how to most elegantly solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extend both to avoid duplicate code. You can do something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;

public class GenericLayout extends ViewGroup{

    private CheckedTextView _checkbox;

    public GenericLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
        strokePaint.setARGB(200, 255, 230, 230);
        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        Rect r = canvas.getClipBounds();
        Rect outline = new Rect(1, 1, r.right - 1, r.bottom - 1);
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, r.top, r.right, r.top, strokePaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // find checked text view
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof CheckedTextView) {
                _checkbox = (CheckedTextView) v;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return _checkbox != null ? _checkbox.isChecked() : false;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (_checkbox != null) {
            _checkbox.setChecked(checked);
        }
    }

    public void toggle() {
        if (_checkbox != null) {
            _checkbox.toggle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}



public class Linear extends LinearLayout {

    GenericLayout generic;

    public Linear(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        generic = new GenericLayout(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        generic.onDraw(canvas);
    }

        ...

}

public class Relative extends RelativeLayout{

    GenericLayout generic;

    public Relative(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        generic.onDraw(canvas);
    }

        ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of what I have learned and been using, there are two ways:

1. You can do what you are trying to avoid (duplicate the class file and replace "extends LinearLayout" with "extends RelativeLayout")
2. You can create 2 interfaces and 1 class: One interface that extends LinearLayout, another one for extending RelativeLayout and the class implementing the methods and variables of the extending interfaces.

I hope that helps a little

Answer (score 0):

You have to rethink your approach.

Seems like you are are using layout to control VIEW logic. Unfortunately your question does not have too much information about what you are trying to achieve.

You have few possibilities:

- implement LAYOUT proxy / delegate with the custom logic (bad approach IMO)
- make a dedicated HANDLER class to control your VIEW objects... these will be independent on the LAYOUT
- make your VIEW object and use VIEW object instead of LAYOUT (probably the way to go)